# how communicate backend without typescript in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I'm trying change https://akveo.github.io/blur-admin/ project. Its controllers are all in js format and I can't migrate them to typescript. So now I can't import any libraries to my controllers (I wanted to use socket.io-client to make a backend with java). I am trying this code

```
$http.get('http://localhost/aa.php').then(function (response) {
        $scope.period_day = response;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

but result is :

```
Object { data: null, status: -1, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "" }
```

But when I open this url in my browser it works fine. Now I just want to make http request to communicate my backend and I don't have any solution. (BlurAdmin project is developed with gulp)

Comment: require(packageName); does not work?

Comment: No it seems this project need angular 11 (I don't know if it is allowed in new version) and it cant use require in js controller

Comment: `$http.get('http://localhost/aa.php').then(function (response) {
        $scope.period_day = response.data;
    })` is what you need. Therefore, read the documentation as this has nothing to do with TypeScript or JavaScript, it's elementary API use error.

Comment: It doesn't work again :(
As I said , response is wrong with status code -1

Comment: Make sureyou are injecting the $http service into your controller

Comment: Hi Marcus , I would be very appreciate if you can say how can I check it?

Comment: you have to add $http as dependency injection in your controller where this api call is made.